# SQL-Server 2005: multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm working with SQL Server 2005, I'm new to SQL so bear with me.

The following aliased SQL query is giving me the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "EquipmentDescription.DESCRIPTION" could not be bound.

SQL:

```
WITH somerows as 
(
    SELECT 
        Mastertable.ID, Mastertable.foo1, Mastertable.foo2, 
        Mastertable.foo3, EquipmentDescription.DESCRIPTION,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Mastertable.ID) AS SeqValue 
    FROM 
        EquipmentDescription 
    LEFT JOIN 
        MasterTable ON EquipmentDescription.foo1 = MasterTable.foo1 
    ORDER BY 
        EquipmentDescription.DESCRIPTION
) 
SELECT * 
FROM somerows  
WHERE SeqValue BETWEEN 0 and 20
```

Background: `Mastertable` has 60,000+ records. I'm using `WITH...as...etc` to request 20 records at a time on the server side.

The `DESCRIPTION` column of `EquipmentDescription` for the purposes of design is not included in `Mastertable`. It is a requirement to include `DESCRIPTION` in the final select.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure equipmentdescription.description exists?  If you just run `select count(description) as cnt from EquipmentDescription` do you get a count or an error?  The table's not aliased so it's not a matter of not finding it.  My guess is either equipmentDescription table or field description doesn't exist in the database you're looking at.  ***OR***... remove order by  could this line be removed? `Order by EquipmentDescription.Description` within the CTE (somerows).. It's not relevant and may throw an error.  Order for row_number is assigned already.

Comment: This is what I have: `mastertable` (which has 60,000+ records), I have `ID`, `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3`. For table 'EquipmentDescription` (which has 75 records), I have `foo1` and `Description`. One requirement is to have one table, `somerows`, with all fields from `mastertable` and `equipmentdescription.Description`, matching at `mastertable.foo1` and `equipmentdescription.foo1` containing records x through y (records 0 to 20, for example). The other requirement is to order `somerows` by any column. I'm stuck on how to sort by `Description`.

Comment: **Clarification:** **Requirement 1:** Gather columns (`foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, `Description`) into one table then sort by any column. **Requirement 2:** Grab records x through y (for example, records 0 to 20)

Comment: `You cannot order by in a CTE`. That may be the cause of your problem. So try your query without the order by clause inside your CTE.

Comment: Alright. If I can't `order by` in a `CTE`, I will go about this another way. Plan A, ditch the CTE entirely and see if I can create a `sorted view`. Plan B (which is a _terrible_ plan), approach the problem one column at a time. I am pretty sure someone has a better idea. In the mean time, I'm going to use what I know thus far.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.105).aspx indicates order by can't be in a CTE unless top is used.  Views can't be ordered either; again, unless top is used. or as you have used it in an analytic.

Comment: Our SQL server is down at the moment, so this gives me some time to brainstorm: What if I were to use two SQL statements (the horror)? One to create the view (gather all columns, etc), and one to do the analytic (sort, etc.) on the view created by the SQL statement? EDIT: _(not sure when or even if to use`ROW_NUMBER()`)_

Comment: SQL Server is still down. I think I'm close to an answer [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx).
Once our Server is up again, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS NUMBER,
    Mastertable.ID, Mastertable.foo1, Mastertable.foo2, 
    Mastertable.foo3, EquipmentDescription.DESCRIPTION,
FROM 
    EquipmentDescription 
RIGHT JOIN 
    MasterTable ON EquipmentDescription.foo1 = MasterTable.foo1
) AS t_MasterTable 
WHERE
    NUMBER BETWEEN 0 and 20
ORDER BY ID
```